# Data structures with java

Tags: java, data-structures

After doing deep dive in collections , I was looking to explore the data structures more with Java please advise which is the best book to explore data structures with Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can like this one :

Java Structures http://www.cs.middlebury.edu/~schar/courses/cs201-s12/js/js.pdf

Answer (score 1):

This is not a programming question, But every one should give answer of this type  question:

**1: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596527754.do 
2: My another favorite book for Java Collections is: Thinking in Java** [Book Link:](http://mindview.net/Books/TIJ4/)

Thanks.

Comment: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/index.html , This link may be useful. :)